# Can we retrieve caller location info using Twilio API using PHP?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am using Twilio API on my php project, I am able to retrieve caller's information like Country Code etc. But I am not able to find something which can also provide its City/State info, here is the API I am using:

```
<?php
    require 'Twilio/autoload.php';
    use Twilio\Rest\Client;

    // Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
    $accountSid = "<ACCOUNT SID>";
    $authToken = "ACCOUNT TOKEN";
    $client = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);

    $number = $client->lookups->phoneNumbers("<PHONE NUMBER>")->fetch();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($number);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Here is the response I get:

```
[properties:protected] => Array
        (
            [callerName] => 
            [countryCode] => US
            [phoneNumber] => <PHONE NUMBER>
            [nationalFormat] => <PHONE NUMBER>
            [carrier] => 
            [addOns] => 
            [url] => https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/<PHONE NUMBER>
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't get address details from the basic, carrier or caller name [Lookups API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups).

However, the [Twilio Add-ons marketplace](https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/add-ons) makes it easy to use third party services to find that information. You could add the [White Pages Pro Caller Identification](https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/add-ons/whitepages-pro-caller-id) or the [Next Caller Advanced Caller ID](https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/add-ons/nextcaller-advanced-caller-id) add-ons and get in depth address information.